# How to generate Word2vec Vectors in Python?

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, text-mining, word2vec

I am trying to generate Word2vec vectors.

I have pandas data frame.

I transformed it into tokens.

`df["token"]`

Used Word2vec from gensim.models

```
model = w2v.Word2Vec(
sentences=df["token"],
seed=seed,
workers=num_workers,
size=num_features,
min_count=min_word_count,
window=context_size,
sample=downsampling
)
```

How do I transform my dataframe df now?

That is what is the equivalent of doing

```
model.transform(df)
```

Comment: What is the content of you dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is composed only of words, you could just make

```
df['new_column'] = model[df['words']]
```

`model['word']` or `model[list()]` both give you the vector representation of your `word` or of your `list`